# How do I solve "invalid header data" for py7zr?

Tags: python, 7zip

I am attempting to create a generic backup program in python using py7zr. So far, it seems to be creating archives successfully, but they cannot be extracted. I have created the following test script to get more info:

```
# path: 7zip_test.py

import py7zr as z
import sys
import os

# create the archive of a given directory
def create_archive(directory):
    # get the name of the directory
    fname = directory.split('\\')[-1]
    # create an archive file named after the directory
    archive = z.SevenZipFile(
        file=f'{fname}.7z',
        mode='w')
    # set archive copmression level to fastest
    archive.compression_level = 0
    # add the directory files to the archive file
    archive.writeall(directory)
    return archive

# extract an archive the the EXTRACT_TEST directory
def extract_archive(archive):
    # create a directory to extract the archive to
    directory = 'EXTRACT_TEST'
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)
    # extract the archive to the directory
    archive.extractall(directory)

# create an archive then extract it
def create_then_extract(directory):
    archive = create_archive(directory)
    extract_archive(archive)
```

When running the create_archive function, I get the following output:

```
C:\Python\backup_test>python 7zip_test.py -a TEST_A
Archive created: <py7zr.py7zr.SevenZipFile object at 0x000002144C5AD6D0>
Archive name: TEST_A.7z
Archive contents: ['TEST_A', 'TEST_A/test1.txt', 'TEST_A/test2.txt', 'TEST_A/testytest', 'TEST_A/testytest/test3.txt']
```

This suggests that the archive is in fact created. However, when running the extract function, I get the following output:

```
C:\Python\backup_test>python 7zip_test.py -e TEST_A.7z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\backup_test\7zip_test.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python\backup_test\7zip_test.py", line 66, in main
    with z.SevenZipFile(file=target, mode='r') as archive:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\py7zr.py", line 407, in __init__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\py7zr.py", line 393, in __init__
    self._real_get_contents(password)
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\py7zr.py", line 428, in _real_get_contents
    self.sig_header = SignatureHeader.retrieve(self.fp)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\archiveinfo.py", line 1099, in retrieve
    obj._read(file)
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\archiveinfo.py", line 1115, in _read
    raise Bad7zFile("invalid header data")
py7zr.exceptions.Bad7zFile: invalid header data
```

And finally, when running the functions together:

```
C:\Python\backup_test>python 7zip_test.py -c TEST_A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\backup_test\7zip_test.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python\backup_test\7zip_test.py", line 71, in main
    create_then_extract(target)
  File "C:\Python\backup_test\7zip_test.py", line 34, in create_then_extract
    extract_archive(archive)
  File "C:\Python\backup_test\7zip_test.py", line 29, in extract_archive
    archive.extractall(directory)
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\py7zr.py", line 990, in extractall
    self._extract(path=path, return_dict=False, callback=callback)
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\py7zr.py", line 632, in _extract
    self.worker.extract(
  File "C:\Users\AdrianDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py7zr\py7zr.py", line 1232, in extract
    src_end = self.src_start + self.header.main_streams.packinfo.packpositions[-1]
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PackInfo' object has no attribute 'packpositions'
```

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please [edit] to show the error messages formatted the same way as the code. Python's stack traces are carefully designed to be read properly in the terminal, and the quote formatting that you've chosen has removed spacing that is crucial to viewing it properly. Please also read [mre] and try to distill the code down to the essentials: for example, if the code that interprets the command-line arguments is working properly, then we aren't interested in that - instead, just show the functions, and how to call them directly in order to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: (It still doesn't look quite right. It will be better if you copy and paste fresh from the terminal, and use code fences instead of trying to indent the code block.)

Comment: Thank you for replying; I have attempted to format the outputs as you asked.

Comment: Because TEST_A is a directory with subfolders and files inside, would the archive created from it be considered a multi-volume archive? And would that mean I can solve this by following the documentation provided [here](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#extraction-from-multi-volume-archive)?

Comment: I would suggest that you start by seeing what happens if you try to open the archive you created with your code, using an existing application for handling 7zip archives. Also, check if the examples from the documentation work for you as advertised. If not, this may be really a tech support question for the library authors, rather than a question for Stack Overflow. Keep in mind that `py7zr` is not a very popular library; ~400 stars on GitHub isn't trivial, but it's far from the top of the leaderboards.